# setup perimissions on app/cache without acl

Tags: symfony, permissions

I've setup the `app/cache/` directory permissions to 0775 (files to 664). And owner to root:www-data.
This works, but when I clear cache, it turns the permissions to 0755 (files to 644) and owner to root:root.
It is supposed to do this:

```
$ rm -rf app/cache/*
$ rm -rf app/logs/*

    $ APACHEUSER=`ps aux | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
    $ sudo chmod +a "$APACHEUSER allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit" app/cache app/logs
    $ sudo chmod +a "`whoami` allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit" app/cache app/logs
```

or this:

```
$ APACHEUSER=`ps aux | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
$ sudo setfacl -R -m u:$APACHEUSER:rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
$ sudo setfacl -dR -m u:$APACHEUSER:rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
```

But acl doesn't work in my VPS, and I'm not able to change as it is said here: [serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/533191/enable-acl-in-vps).
I've seen this in Symfony2 documentation:

`Without using ACL`

`If you don't have access to changing the ACL of the directories, you will need to change the umask so that the cache and log directories will be group-writable or world-writable (depending if the web server user and the command line user are in the same group or not). To achieve this, put the following line at the beginning of the app/console, web/app.php and web/app_dev.php files:`

```
umask(0002); // This will let the permissions be 0775

// or

umask(0000); // This will let the permissions be 0777
```

`Note that using the ACL is recommended when you have access to them on your server because changing the umask is not thread-safe.`

The questions are: 
**Is there any safer way to setup the permissions properly without acl?** 
**Is the `umask` usage a dangerous way?**. **What does "not thread-safe" means in this case?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is to set your cli user(who runs the cache clear command) the same as the webserver user. In your case this means change owner of this files from `root:www-data` to `www-data:www-data` and run the cache clear command with the `www-data` user.

About `umask`, according to official PHP documentation:

> Avoid using this function in multithreaded webservers. It is better to change the file permissions with chmod() after creating the file. Using umask() can lead to unexpected behavior of concurrently running scripts and the webserver itself because they all use the same umask.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Indeed, that's what I've recently been doing, the only way I've found.